# mongoose match multiple ids and count if duplicate found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of ids and it may contain duplicates, so ignore duplicates and count the occurrence of total duplicates. I will explain it in details.

`IDS`

```
[
  5fe10a8c4d6b0fb7f70bbf84,
  5fe10a8c4d6b0fb7f70bbf84,
  5ff2aad439a8602fd872ab7c
]
```

I have used the below code to get the result,

```
var user_id = [
  5fe10a8c4d6b0fb7f70bbf84,
  5fe10a8c4d6b0fb7f70bbf84,
  5ff2aad439a8602fd872ab7c
];

User.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: {
          $in: user_id
        }
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
  ],
  (err, resp) => {
      console.log(resp)
  })
```

The output for above code is,

```
[
  { _id: 5ff2aad439a8602fd872ab7c, count: 1 },
  { _id: 5fe10a8c4d6b0fb7f70bbf84, count: 1 }
]
```

The required output is,

```
[
  { _id: 5ff2aad439a8602fd872ab7c, count: 1 },
  { _id: 5fe10a8c4d6b0fb7f70bbf84, count: 2 }
]
```

I have tried many code but no success, is there anyway to achieve required output.

Comment: Do those duplicates actually live in your collection or they are only in that `user_id`array you're using to match? Because your output counts up what's actually in the collection, and since mongodb does not allow duplicate `_id`, you get those 1,1 counts.

Comment: only in `user_id`

Comment: Is it a field in the database?

Comment: Yeah looks like what you're trying to accomplish is a pure JS task - count dups in an array. Mongodb shouldn't really play a role here.

Comment: Your `$match` brings back **unique** `_id`s from the User collection regardless of how many duplicate `_id`s you pass into your pipeline. So by the time your aggregation reaches `$group`, it's dealing with an array of unique `_id`s. So you will never get the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

you trying to get the count from _id. _id is unique for all the documents so you need to change the _id to some other fields which is not unique.
example,

**table**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    values: [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    values: [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    values: [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    values: [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
]
```

**Query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      id: {
        $in: [
          1,
          3
        ]
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```